# How do I set a default style in XAML with Setters?

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

Via a VisualState Setter, how do I revert a control to its default style?

```
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <pbixaml:DeviceTypeTrigger DeviceType="Other"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="flip.Style" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
```

I tried using null, but that didn't work (was ignored actually). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset any VisualState setter to a *default* value, use an empty string.

```
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <pbixaml:DeviceTypeTrigger DeviceType="Other"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="flip.Style" Value=""/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
```

With default value, I mean the style that has been set in your XAML code:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flip" Text="Test" />
```

Here your VisualState will revert to the default built-in Windows style.

```
<FlipView x:Name="flip" Style="{StaticResource MyGreenStyle}" Text="Test" />
```

Here your VisualState will revert whatever other style used to `MyGreenStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign an empty style to the control (kind of hack...):

```
<VisualStateGroup>
   <VisualState>
      <VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <pbixaml:DeviceTypeTrigger DeviceType="Other"/>
      </VisualState.StateTriggers>
      <VisualState.Setters>
         <Setter Target="flip.Style">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <Style TargetType="FlipView"/>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </VisualState.Setters>
   </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

But I suggest you to do the reverse thing, set the style only in states that you wish, instead of clearing the style in states that you don't.

```
<VisualStateGroup>
   <VisualState>
      <VisualState.StateTriggers>
         <pbixaml:DeviceTypeTrigger DeviceType="[AllKnown]"/>
      </VisualState.StateTriggers>
      <VisualState.Setters>
         <Setter Target="flip.Style" Value="[What you usually want]"/>      
       </VisualState.Setters>
   </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
..
..
<FlipView .... />   <!-- do not set style here ->
```

in this way, when the [AllKnown] device type is not active, style is cleared by the visual state manager.